# Previous form data being applied to Form for editing in django

Tags: python, django

I have a way for users to edit comments they posted in Django but now Im trying to implement a feature where when users go to edit their comments the previous comment is displayed in the form.
This way when a user goes to edit their comment it will show what they said previously in the form field.
views.py

```
def update_comment(request, year, month, day, post,  comment_id = None ):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    user = request.user
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id))
    if (comment.name != user):
        raise PermissionDenied
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id))
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post = post
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user
            comment_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'posts/update_comment.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form, 'comment_id':comment_id })
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import PostListView, PostCreateView,PostUpdateView
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    #path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/update/',PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/<comment_id>/',views.update_comment, name='update_comment'),
]
```

update_comment.html

```
{% extends "Main/Base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:update_comment' post.publish.year post.publish.month post.publish.day post.slug comment_id %}">
{{ comment_form.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Update comment"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: In the update form you can send the comments data and id in that form input.

Comment: could you show me when you mean with code? please

Comment: so what's going wrong? At a glance, your code looks OK, the `CommentForm` instance has the correct `Comment` instance, and you're passing it to the template.

Comment: When I load the update_comment.html the form is blank I want to form to be populated with the comment that the user is trying to edit

Comment: oh, now I look at it again, it's because of this line `comment_form = CommentForm()` just before the `return` statement. Remove that and you should be OK?

Comment: thanks for the advice I replaced `comment_form=CommentForm()` with `comment_form = CommentForm(instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id))` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `comment_form=CommentForm()` with `comment_form = CommentForm(instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id))` and it worked now when I go to edit a comment it shows the text the comment previously had